# To write chat programming using UDP and MQTT protocol in Android

Tags: android, network-programming, udp, mqtt, udpclient

I am new in Android programming and don't know how to work with UDP and MQTT protocol in android device

I want to build an application for chatting android to android device within room connected to same Wi-Fi router.

But I don't know what IP address and port I should bind to DatagramSocket and DatagramPacket.

I tried lot of examples from online but I didn't understand how it will work in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MQTT requires TCP, it is a statefull protocol, you can not implement it with UDP

There is a similar protocol called [MQTT-SN](http://mqtt.org/new/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/MQTT-SN_spec_v1.2.pdf) which can be implemented with a stateless protocol like UDP.

But both of these are still going to require a broker running somewhere to coordinate the delivery of messages to subscribers to given topics

Comment: Thank you @hardillb

Answer (score 1):

I found code to send message on UDP protocol which works as below.

```
public class SendUDP extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String message;

    public SendUDP(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void[] params) {

        try {
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(13001);
            byte[] senddata = new byte[message.length()];
            senddata = message.getBytes();

            InetSocketAddress server_addr;
            DatagramPacket packet;

            server_addr = new InetSocketAddress(getBroadcastAddress(getApplicationContext()).getHostAddress(), 13001);
            packet = new DatagramPacket(senddata, senddata.length, server_addr);
            socket.setReuseAddress(true);
            socket.setBroadcast(true);
            socket.send(packet);
            Log.e("Packet", "Sent");

            socket.disconnect();
            socket.close();
        } catch (SocketException s) {
            Log.e("Exception", "->" + s.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "->" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String text) {
        super.onPostExecute(text);
    }
}
```

and below function for fetching broadcast IP address of device connected in the LAN network through which all other devices in the LAN will receive this message.

```
public static InetAddress getBroadcastAddress(Context context) throws IOException {
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    DhcpInfo dhcp = wifi.getDhcpInfo();
    // handle null somehow

    int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;
    byte[] quads = new byte[4];
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        quads[k] = (byte) (broadcast >> (k * 8));
    return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
}
```

and this will send UDP message after executing this as

```
new SendUDP("Hello All Device").execute();
```

It works like a charm!