# Android Sockets not working in run mode only

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I'm trying to send a message through android sockets but whenever I try to open the socket in run mode I just get an SocketException.  Here is the strackTrace:

```
04-03 11:08:55.761 5597-6574/com.example.username.shutterdoor W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort
04-03 11:08:55.768 5597-6574/com.example.username.shutterdoor W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
04-03 11:08:55.768 5597-6574/com.example.username.shutterdoor W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:535)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:427)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:210)
04-03 11:08:55.769 5597-6574/com.example.username.shutterdoor W/System.err:     at com.example.username.shutterdoor.UnconfiguredDeviceCheckTask.doInBackground(UnconfiguredDeviceCheckTask.java:34)
04-03 11:08:55.769 5597-6574/com.example.username.shutterdoor W/System.err:     at com.example.username.shutterdoor.UnconfiguredDeviceCheckTask.doInBackground(UnconfiguredDeviceCheckTask.java:11)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

And here is my code:

```
public class UnconfiguredDeviceCheckTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Integer>{

    final static String DEFAULT_DEVICE_IP = "192.168.4.1";
    final static int DEFAULT_DEVICE_PORT = 7510;
    final static String REQUEST_DEVICE_CHECK = "C8\r";

    private AsyncResult resultCallback;
    private int resultCode = 0;

    public UnconfiguredDeviceCheckTask(AsyncResult result){
        resultCallback = result;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try{
            Log.i("Wifi","Sleeping");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            Log.i("Wifi","Async connection task is interrupted while sleeping");
        }
        try {
            Log.i("Wifi","Attempting to open socket");
            Socket socket = new Socket(DEFAULT_DEVICE_IP, DEFAULT_DEVICE_PORT);
            try {
                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                try{
                    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    out.write(REQUEST_DEVICE_CHECK.getBytes());

                    socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
                    while(resultCode == 0) {
                        resultCode = in.read();
                        Log.i("Wifi","Setting result code to " + resultCode);
                    }
                }catch (IOException e){
                    Log.e("Wifi","Could not create PrintStream");
                }
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e("Wifi","Could not create inputStream");
            }


            Log.i("Wifi","No response, Connection timed out");

        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("Wifi","Unable to create socket to 192.168.4.1");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultCode;
    }
```

The socket however opens fine in debug mode when the breakpoint is set where the socket is created. I dont understand how to fix this, Any help?

Comment: Sorry but i've just managed to solve this by setting thread.sleep to 10 seconds instead of 5. This took me a whole day

Comment: You can check my post on this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49124580/6549856